# Arduino with Ultrasonic sensor integrated but vibration motor not working according to the code

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

Here's my code after editing the measurement had error. Now the ultrasonic measurement is working but the vibration motor is not vibrating.

```
#define trigPin1 8
#define echoPin1 7
#define motorPin1 13

long duration, distance, UltraSensor;

void setup()
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600); // to use the serial monitor.
  pinMode(trigPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin1, INPUT);
  //pinMode(motorPin1, OUTPUT);

}

void SonarSensor(int trigPin, int echoPin)
{
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration / 2) / 29.1;
  delay(100);
}

void loop()
{ 
  SonarSensor(trigPin1, echoPin1);
  UltraSensor = distance;
  Serial.print(distance); // print out the distance on Serial Monitor
  Serial.println("cm");
//
  if (distance <= 60 && distance >= 45) // Checking the distance, you can change the value
  {
    digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH); // motor on
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW); // motor off
    delay(200);
  } 
  else if(distance < 45 && distance >=30)
  {
    digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH); // when greater than 100cm
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
    delay(100);
  } 
  else if(distance < 30) 
  {
   digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH);
   delay(50);
   digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
   delay(50); 
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: Cut out everything from your sketch except the distance measuring. Forget the rest for now. Get the distance measuring working first.

Comment: And while you are at it, disconnect the motor and post a picture clearly showing how you have the ultrasonic sensor wired to the arduino.

Comment: After i cut out everything except the distance measuring part also not working. You can check below. Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: do not put updates into comments ... update the original question ... there is an `edit` button for doing that ... while you are at it, change the title of your question to `Arduino not measuring distance correctly`, because that is the problem, it is not a motor problem.

Comment: I already edited my code and now the measurement is working but the motor is not vibrating. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to uncomment the line that defines the motor as an output device.

//pinMode(motorPin1, OUTPUT);